# SAS PassThru to Snowflake using EXECUTE( %include <program?) by SNOW; Error

Tags: sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This process works with pass thru to Teradata.  We are migrating to Snowflake.  I create a program using a data step and put statements INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE VALUES('VAR', 'VAR', 'VAR, VAR', 'VAR, 'VAR', 'VAR');  The execute () by snow; works when I copy each record into the direct sas code.  However, we don't know how many rows we will have on a given day and this process is automated, so the this was a way to be hand free.

The TD code that works great:

```
EXECUTE(
  BT;
  %include "/&srv./&fldr./programs/ORG_JOB_DPT_LKP.sas";
  ET; 
 ) BY TERA;
```

Previous errors are similar for the BT and ET:

**ERROR: CLI execute error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected '%'.**

I have also tried to send the multiple insert rows over as a macro variable with a %let = %();
I receive the same unexpected "&" when trying to call the variable.
I haven't been able to find any documentation that suggests this shouldn't work.

Comment: Does the code you are trying to run in Snowflake work with some other interface to Snowflake?  Does it work without the %INCLUDE?  That is just type the statements into the current SAS code you are running instead of storing them in a second file. Try it with just a couple of lines of code.  If that works it might be related to the size of the overall statement.

Comment: What are BT and ET statements?  Are those Teradata specific? Or will Snowflake understand them also?